# Recorrer <table> con javascript y pasar datos a ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap

Actualmente mantengo una plantilla bootstrap que dentro de sus elementos existe las TABLES para visualizar la información que se obtiene de la base de datos, cuyos registros se visualizan de 10 en 10 gracias a la paginación de este elemento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aqui no hay novedad en este proceso, más requiero hacer modificaciones en los registros de la pantalla y los mismos grabarlos después de estos cambios en otra tabla peror de la base de datos, por lo que procedo a recorres la misma con la siguiente instrucción de javascript para pasar por ajax los registros a la capa de persistencia

```
$('#dynamic tbody tr').each(function() {
var neta = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text();
var porcentaje = $(this).find('td').eq(4).text();
var comision = $(this).find('td').eq(4).text();
//
var fila = {
  neta,
  porcentaje,
  comision
};
filas.push(fila);
});
//
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "home.php?c=liquidaciones&a=guardardetallepre",
data: {valores : JSON.stringify(filas) },
success: function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
}
});
```

Aquí es donde nace el problema ya que solo recorre los 10 registros que se visualizan en base a la plantilla y su paginación y lo que requiero es que recorra todos sin excepcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es más por que los usuarios están acostumbrados a trabajar página a página las modificaciones de los datos y obviamente el sistema para ellos falla ya que graba solo los datos de la página actual donde se encuentre el usuario trabajando.

Comment: Entiendo que el problema es que en tu DOM sólo tienes cargados esos 10 registros. El resto se cargarán cada vez que cambies de página (con una llamada AJAX interna para obtener los registros del 11 al 20, del 21 al 30, etc.). De ahí que al obtener las filas sólo obtengas 10. Lo único que se me ocurre es que intentes obtener todos los registros (no sé cómo los cargas inicialmente) y con eso hacer tu llamada AJAX.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y te comento que mi modelo MVC coloca los datos de los registros en una variable array que luego la dibujo con un foreach, pero al desplegar los registros, existe la posibilidad de cambiar o ajustar la información y por eso no podría enviar los datos del array ya que se ajusta la información en la tabla en función de los procesos de usuarios...